# Kubernetes: How to setup TLS termination in the Load Balancer on AWS using Nginx Ingress Controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, ssl, nginx-ingress, amazon-elb

In the documentation of Nginx Ingress for AWS it says:

```
By default, TLS is terminated in the ingress controller. But it is also possible to terminate TLS in the Load Balancer.
```

Link: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#tls-termination-in-aws-load-balancer-nlb

So, I follow the instructions: set AWS ACM certification, set VPC CIDR and deploy.

Then check ingress nginx service:
`kubectl get service --namespace ingress-nginx`

```
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP                                                                     PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.100.124.56   adba41948av49484z55137c374e1e17d-09af54e014df8676.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com   80:31985/TCP,443:32330/TCP   17h
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.100.175.52   <none>                                                                          443/TCP                      17h
```

In the AWS console, the Load Balancer has necessary certificate and all seems fine.

Next, I create Ingress rules and Service with type: ClusterIP

- Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    name: test-app-pod
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP
```

- Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-app-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: foobar.com # forwards to LB
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: test-app-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Check the Ingress:
`kubectl get ingress`

```
NAME              CLASS   HOSTS                         ADDRESS                                                                         PORTS   AGE
test-app-ingress   nginx   foobar.com   adba41948av49484z55137c374e1e17d-09af54e014df8676.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com   80      29m
```

So I am just stuck here.
When I go to http://foobar.com  -- it works perfectly fine.
But when I go to https://foobar.com - it says 'Could not resolve host: foobar.com'

And I would expect that when I go to https://foobar.com then it terminates TLS on LB and sends the traffic to the service.

I have also found an article, where it is described the same, and in comments there are the same questions like I have, so I am not the only one :D : https://habeeb-umo.medium.com/using-nginx-ingress-in-eks-with-tls-termination-in-a-network-load-balancer-1783fc92935 (I followed this instructions also - no luck as well)

**UPDATE**:
as per @mdaniel
When I do `curl -v http://foobar.com` and `curl -v https://foobar.com` - it both says `Could not resolve host: foobar.com`:
http:

```
    * Could not resolve host: foobar.com
    * Closing connection 0
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: foobar.com
```

https:

```
    * Could not resolve host: foobar.com
    * Closing connection 0
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: foobar.com
```

And in the browser when I go to http://foobar.com - it opens the page OK, BUT when I refresh the page it shows 'This site can’t be reached'.

---

**UPDATE2:**

I think I have found an issue.

I used httpd container inside the pod and opened 8080 port

```
spec:
      containers:
        - name: some-app
          image: httpd:2.4.54
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

So when I do port-forward
`kubectl port-forward test-app-deployment-f59984d85-qckr9 8081:8080`
The first GET request http://127.0.0.1:8081 is fine, but after another one - it fails

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8081 -> 8080
Forwarding from [::1]:8081 -> 8080
Handling connection for 8081
E1124 11:48:43.466682   94768 portforward.go:406] an error occurred forwarding 8081 -> 8080: error forwarding port 8080 to pod d79172ed802e00f93a834aab7b89a0da053dba00ad327d71fff85f582da9819e, uid : exit status 1: 2022/11/24 10:48:43 socat[15820] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:8080, 16): Connection refused
```

So I changed containerPort to 80 and it helped:

```
spec:
      containers:
        - name: some-app
          image: httpd:2.4.54
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80 # changed port to 80
```

Run port forwarding: `kubectl port-forward test-app-deployment-f59984d85-qckr9 8081:80`
Make 3 GET requests http://127.0.0.1:8081

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8081 -> 80
Forwarding from [::1]:8081 -> 80
Handling connection for 8081
Handling connection for 8081
Handling connection for 8081
```

Comment: This is suspiciously close to off-topic for a programming stack exchange, but your cited experience of "Could not resolve host" has nothing to do with TLS termination; consider [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74552001/edit) to show the output of both `curl -v http://foobar.com` and `curl -v https://foobar.com`

Comment: hmmm

It both says `Could not resolve host: foobar.com`

http:
```
    * Could not resolve host: foobar.com
    * Closing connection 0
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: foobar.com
```

https:
```
    * Could not resolve host: foobar.com
    * Closing connection 0
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: foobar.com
```

And in the browser when I go to http://foobar.com - it opens the page BUT, when I refresh multiple times the page it sometimes shows OK, sometimes 'This site can’t be reached'.
It seems like this is LB or worker node issue. Will update my question also

Comment: @mdaniel Thank you so much for your help. I have put other findings into the UPDATE2 section in the question. Still don't know how the containerPort could affect that. I expected either 8080 - fails or 8080 works fine all the time, but not only for the 1st request